# What is behind MVVM Light's SimpleIoC

Tags: .net, mvvm, ioc-container

I only need to know what is behind the MVVM Light's SimpleIoC? Is one of the existing ones (Unity, Castle Windsor, StructureMap, MEF, maybe the Simple Injector ...)? Or it is simple one implemented by the MVVM Light's develop team?

Is there a way of make that SimpleIoC to work with a specific IoC? Or should I use the [Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody answer this question, I made a research. I can't wait to know what is behind SimpleIoC, this question [Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12233/lbugnion) who may answer it.

But the second one (Is there a way of make that SimpleIoC to work with a specific IoC? Or should I use the Service Locator?) I can answer it now.

The thing is that the `SimpleIoc.Default` is an implementation of the `IServiceLocator` interface, and MVVMLight Toolkit works using the Service Locator pattern. So if we wish to use any IoC library, we just need to implement the `IServiceLocator` interface, and then we may use it.

For instance, using the Unity IoC:

```
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        //ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));
        //If we wish use another IoC we must implement the IServiceLocator interface


        ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        ////{
        ////    // Create design time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Create run time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        ////}

        container.RegisterType<MainViewModel>();
        //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }
```

This code is the constructor of the ViewModelLocator. The UnityServiceLocator class implement the IServiceLocator interface...

Comment: There is a post that shows how this is done in more detail [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/655515/Integrating-Unity-Container-with-MVVM-Light-Framew). However the IServiceLocator interface is a bit constricting. I think you have to go outside of it in order to get the full power of unity